# Passing image from ViewController to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I try to pass an image from one `ViewController1` to another `ViewController2` when a button is tapped. I am using `segues` in my Storyboard.

**ViewController1**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    @IBAction func editPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let editViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditImageViewController") as! EditImageViewController
        editViewController.imageForEdit = imageView.image!
        print(imageView)
        print(imageView.image!)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(editViewController, animated: true)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

`print(imageView)` results in

> some(UIImageView: 0x7fc34df0e630; frame = (8 29; 303 443); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x60000023e520)

and `print(imageView.image!)` in

> size {3000, 2002} orientation 0 scale 1.000000

**ViewController2**

```
import UIKit

class EditImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageForEdit = UIImage()

    @IBOutlet weak var editingImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        editingImage.image = imageForEdit
        print(imageForEdit)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

`print(imageForEdit)` results in

> size {0, 0} orientation 0 scale 1.000000

Why is that? Why isnt the image passed to `ViewController2`?

Comment: Try move local variable  `let editViewController` from function to your `ViewController ` class.

Comment: @AleX That is not working. `Cannot use instance member 'storyboard' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Comment: Write `var editViewController: EditImageViewController?`, then in your function -> `editViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditImageViewController") as! EditImageViewController`

Comment: @AleX No, I am still getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this could be a lot simpler.  If you're using a Storyboard with a segue, you can easily accomplish this in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.  Here's a sample storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

In this case, ViewController has a segue on the `Edit Image` button to the `EditImageViewController`.

When you push that button, you get your `prepare(for segue:` call.  Here's a sample ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "icon8", ofType: "png")
    var anEditableImage:UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let imagePath = imagePath {
            anEditableImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        }
    }

     // MARK: - Navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? EditImageViewController {
            destination.imageForEdit = anEditableImage
        }
     }
}
```

And here's the `EditImageViewController`:

```
class EditImageViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageForEdit:UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(imageForEdit ?? "Image was nil")
    }
}
```

Using `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` is the preferred way for a Storyboard-based app to pass data between View Controllers.  It's very simple and it works.

Sample project is here if you want to see the working code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eog01bmha67c5mv/PushImage.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Replace   `var imageForEdit = UIImage()` with     `var imageForEdit : UIImage?`

i test code my self , make sure that  `imageView` have image

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `print(imageForEdit)` in `ViewController2` results in `nil` then.

Comment: i'm sure you have some thing else wrong but above code work

Comment: `imageView` has image. I select it from the galery and its displayed. You also can see in the print statements that it has an image. It just doesnt pass through to the other `ViewController2`

Comment: try to pass image directly  without `UIImageView` code have no error

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `editViewController.imageForEdit = UIImage.init(named: "anyImage")`   set any image for test Directly

Comment: your code above have no problem , i checked it my self

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageForEdit: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        editingImage.image = imageForEdit
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: In which place?

Comment: In here: `var imageForEdit: UIImage? { didSet { editingImage.image = imageForEdit }}`, more precisely here `editingImage.image = imageForEdit`

Comment: set `editViewController.imageForEdit = imageView.image!` after `navigationController?.pushViewController(editViewController, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an public variable so you can pase data from one viewcontroller to another view controller.

```
class variables
{
    static var image = UIImage()
}
```

the 2 controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var anotherviewcontroller: UIImageView!

anotherviewcontroller.image = variables.image
```